# Why default constructor does not appear for value types?

Tags: c#, .net

The below snippet gives me a list of constructors and methods of a type.

```
static void ReflectOnType(Type type)
{
    Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
    Console.WriteLine("------------");
    List<ConstructorInfo> constructors =
            type.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic |BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Default).ToList();

    List<MethodInfo> methods = type.GetMethods().ToList();

    Type baseType = type.BaseType;

    while (baseType != null)
    {
            constructors.AddRange(baseType.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                              BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Default));
            methods.AddRange(baseType.GetMethods());
            baseType = baseType.BaseType;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Reflection on {0} type", type.Name);

    for (int i = 0; i < constructors.Count; i++)
    {
         Console.Write("Constructor: {0}.{1}", constructors[i].DeclaringType.Name, constructors[i].Name);
         Console.Write("(");
         ParameterInfo[] parameterInfos = constructors[i].GetParameters();
         if (parameterInfos.Length > 0)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < parameterInfos.Length; j++)
             {
                 if (j > 0)
                 {
                     Console.Write(", ");
                 }
                 Console.Write("{0} {1}", parameterInfos[j].ParameterType, parameterInfos[j].Name);
             }
         }
         Console.Write(")");

         if (constructors[i].IsSpecialName)
         {
             Console.Write(" has 'SpecialName' attribute");
         }
         Console.WriteLine();
     }
     Console.WriteLine();

     for (int i = 0; i < methods.Count; i++)
     {
         Console.Write("Method: {0}.{1}", methods[i].DeclaringType.Name, methods[i].Name);
         // Determine whether or not each field is a special name.
         if (methods[i].IsSpecialName)
         {
             Console.Write(" has 'SpecialName' attribute");
         }
         Console.WriteLine();
     }
 }
```

But when I pass an ‘int’ type to this method, why don’t I see the implicit constructor in the output? Or, how do I modify the above code to list the default constructor as well (in case I’m missing something in my code).

Comment: Interesting read may be: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/12/10/value-types-and-parameterless-constructors.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C# (and most CLI languages) - specifying a parameterless constructor on a struct is forbidden, and as such, a struct created in C# (and most other .NET languages) will not even have a parameterless constructor defined in the IL.  The CLR always initializes value types using defined rules (basically, filling all values with zero equivalents), and C# enforces that as the only option.

Since the default, parameterless constructor does not exist in a C# generated struct, it does not display when using reflection.

Comment: Reed, you have any MSDN documentation or an article about this so I can learn more?

Comment: @Arun: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288208(VS.71).aspx  "Structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors. Struct members are automatically initialized to their default values."

Comment: @Arun: Current - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx    - "Each value type has an implicit default constructor that initializes the default value of that type."

Comment: Curious - why the downvoting?  This is true **for C#** - granted, you can define a constructor in the CLI, in which case, it does show up via reflection - but it's impossible to do from C# (which is the tag on the question...)

Comment: And it *can* be "overridden", just not in C#. But it's clearly not very useful since the CLR doesn't always run it in places you might expect it to.

Comment: @Ani: Actually, even in those cases, the CLR does do that.  It may also, in some corner cases, call a default constructor, but it does that after the default initialization.  Look at stack allocated variables, for example.... (They'll ignore the constructor.)  Jon even mentions this in his article.

Comment: @Ani: I guess we can disagree - the CLR **ALWAYS** does the default initialization (even if it later calls the constructor), but in C#, it's completely left out of the IL.  My answer explicitly mentions that it's for C#.

Comment: "there is no reason to show it using reflection" - Your answer seems to suggest that the reflection API is declining to *show* a ctor because it has figured out that the calling code was originally written in C#. That's not correct at all.

Comment: There's no disagreement that the zeroing out always happens, but the answer is slighly misleading with respect to a) the overridability b) what the reflection is doing. I don't want to appear pedantic - this is just a phrasing issue. If you can just clarify your meaning with an edit..

Comment: @Ani: That wording make you happier?

Answer (score 1):

This is a difference between the C# and CLI specifications. C# says that all value-types have a (non-overridable) default parameterless constructor, but this is not the case with the CLI.

In many cases, the run-time will *not* run the default constructor even if it exists (this is reasonable since most languages that target CIL don't let you write one); doing nothing after filling the struct with zeroes. Here's an [interesting article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/12/10/value-types-and-parameterless-constructors/) by Jon Skeet that experiments with hacking a parameterless constructor into a struct - it sometimes runs, and sometimes doesn't, depending on context.

In any case, the reason the reflection API doesn't show you such a parameterless constructor on that type is because there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want any constructor to go with you can get the list of contructors by

```
var consturctorList = type.GetContructors();
```

If your value type a struct with no explicitly defined constructors, you will get an empty list above since implicit constructor is not available for messing up with it in reflection, you can use deserialization method

```
FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(Type type)
```

Answer (score -1):

> Why default constructor does not appear for value types?

In short, because constructor for value types NOT EXIST.

More detailed explanation [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ad954b62-7cca-4894-828d-2fdee4445209/default-constructor-in-value-types?forum=clr):

> To my knowledge,there's no default constructor defined by CLR , the
> default constructor for reference types is generated by C# compiler
> itself (or other language compilers). So CLR has no default
> constructor for neither of reference or value types.
>
> For reference types C# defines default parametreless ctor , which
> call's upon base class ctor. But that's the c# compiler's job to emit
> this default ctor code, no CLR. Now for valuetype this does not happen
> (that is no default ctor is emitted by compiler)

So, since "int" is Valye Type, not exist any constructor for it.