# Invoke default parameterless valuetype constructor via Reflection.Emit

Tags: .net, reflection.emit

Is this at all possible, given `Type.GetConstructors()` will not return such a constructor?

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687289/why-default-constructor-does-not-appear-for-value-types) but it still does not solve the problem.

Example:

How to emit `default(Nullable<int>)` or `default(Guid)`?

PS: I am not interested in workarounds. I can guess a few, but it would be impossible for me to integrate them directly into my compiler without substantial modifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grrr. Found my answer.

You use `OpCodes.Initobj`  :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.initobj(VS.100).aspx