# Why does new() constraint allows enum as type argument in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

While learning about Generics I came to knew about *Constraints on Type Parameters*.
One of these constraints is **new()** constraint. According to Microsoft:

> The type argument must have a public parameterless constructor. When
>   used together with other constraints, the new() constraint must be
>   specified last.

Now I have a code like this.

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class A { }

    struct S { }

    enum E { }

    class Generics
    {
        public static void GenericMethod<T>() where T : new() 
        {
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Generics.GenericMethod<A>(); // Line 1
            Generics.GenericMethod<S>(); // Line 2
            Generics.GenericMethod<E>(); // Line 3
        }
    }
}
```

- Line 1 does not generate error bcoz classes have default parameterless
  constructor.
- Line 2 does not generate error bcoz structs have default parameterless
  constructor. And
- Line 3 does not generate error but **WHY?**

Why does new() constraint allows enum to be passed as type argument?

Also I am able to do this

```
E e = new E();
```

in the above code.

Does this mean enums have parameterless constructor by default?

**Edited:** After reading answers and comments I thought enums contain default constructor. So I used reflection to see if I can print on the console the default constructor of enum E. The code is as follows

```
Type T = typeof(E);
Console.WriteLine("Constructors");
ConstructorInfo[] constructors = T.GetConstructors();
foreach (var constructor in constructors)
{
    Console.WriteLine(constructor.ToString());
}
```

But it doesn't prints anything.

So the question still remains **Does an enum has a default parameterless constructor or not?**

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question already? You've shown that enums do have a public parameter-less constructor.

Comment: But I can't explicitly define another like in a class.

Comment: Enums are a class type, it's inheritance hierarchy is from System.Object and System.ValueType, it has a constructor, to read more about it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Here I am talking about the type enum not about class Enum they are both different.

Comment: @RyanWilson That is not what is usually called a class type. A class type is usually taken to mean a reference type which is not an interface (sometimes not a delegate type either). In any case, an enum is a value type. But it is true that it is inheriting, in a sense, the reference type `System.Enum` whose base class is `System.ValueType` (base `System.Object`).

Comment: Enums are mostly just ints, which also have a parameter-less default constructor (`new int()` is perfectly fine, but awkward) like any other object which doesn’t explicitly specifies a constructor.

Comment: @ckuri are you saying that enums borrow parameterless constructor from their underllying type.

Comment: Then why didn't the reflection code printed any constructors on the console.

Comment: No, they don’t borrow - my comment was more about that enums for most of the parts just behave like their underlying type. The default constructor for value types is implicit. GetConstructors or any other reflection methods are likely to only return what is actually defined and won’t return syntactic sugar elements or language constructs. To go back to an int: technically it doesn’t need a constructor, because as a primitive there is nothing to construct - it’s just there, however language-wise every object has to have constructor.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen While I agree that your definition of class type applies to most cases, MSDN still classifies ENUM as a base class "Enum is the base class for all enumerations in the .NET Framework." So, even though it is an abstract class, it still meets the criteria of not being an interface or delegate type.

Comment: @RyanWilson Yes, the special abstract type `System.Enum` is a reference type which is not an interface and not a delegate type. However, you cannot use `System.Enum` as a type parameter `T` which has the constraint `where T : new()`. No abstract type can fulfil the `new()` constraint. It is different with an enum type (and `System.Enum` is ___not___ an enum type!). As an example, the type `Test.E` from the program above, that type is a value type. Any enum type such as `Test.E` (or, say, `System.DayOfWeek`) is allowed as the `T` constrained to `where T : new()`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I think we are agreeing on everything discussed, maybe my calling it a class type was not as descriptive as it should have been.

Answer (score 4):

This is allowed because all specific enum types are [*value types*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14561365/335858). Hence, C# gives them a default constructor:

> Each value type has an implicit default constructor that initializes the default value of that type.

Comment: But why can't I explicitly define a constructor in an enum.

Comment: @Learner The only explicit members you can write in an `enum`, are the (automatically `public`) enumeration constants.

Comment: @Learner and what exactly are you going to do in that constructor if you were allowed to define it?

Comment: @Evk If it were allowed (it is not), you could have a non-static constructor that took in one or more arguments and contained logic to determine the value the enum. By unconditionally assigning to the field `this.value__` in the constructor body.

Comment: Just like @Jeppe said I could have some kind of logic to determine the value of enum.

Answer (score 0):

Every value type `T` is allowed with the constraint `where T : new()`, including every enum type.

When `new T()` is used, it corresponds to the zero value of the value type. It is the same as `default(T)` for value types.

There is a more specific constraint, `where T : struct`, also allowing enum types (but not `Nullable<>`). This constraint "implies" the `where T : new()` in the sense that you cannot specify both because `struct` automatically contains `new()`. Again, in the case of a value type, `new T()` is the same as `default(T)`.

---

**EDIT:** To address the new question:

> Does an enum has a default parameterles constructor or not?

No, in reality a value type (including an enum) does not have this zero-parameter instance constructor. But the syntax `new E()` is still allowed, and produces the same "zero" value as does `default(E)`. And it is specifically permitted to use a value type for a generic parameter `T` constrained to `where T : new()`.

See related thread [Why default constructor does not appear for value types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687289/)